# how to have XSL template not repeat the table for each record?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

the template displays a dataset that's generated from the database. the dataset has many rows in it.

`<xsl:template match="Photos">` gets executed for each row that's in the dataset. every row in the dataset has one image.

I want `<td id="tdImage">` only to be repeated, but the rest to be executed only once.

the whole purpose of this is to have the images displayed horizontally, not vertically.

[what it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orRFp.png)

```
 <xsl:template match="Photos">

<table width = "600">

  <tr style="width:600;">
    <xsl:if test =  "SequenceNumber=1" >
      <td colspan ="5" class ="input">Photos:</td>
    </xsl:if>
  </tr>

  <tr style="width:600;">


        <td id="tdImage">
          <table width ="150">

            <tr>
              <td style ="padding-left:15px">
                <table width ="150">
                  <tr style="width:150px;">
                    <td style="width:135px;">
                      <a href = '{src}'  style="font-size:10px;">
                        <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>
                      </a>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="width:150px;">
                    <td  style="width:150px;">

                      <img  type = "hidden"  Width="75" Height="75" src='{src}' />

                    </td>

                  </tr>


                </table>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: an example for the dataset

```
    SequenceNumber    |    FileName    |               src
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          1           |   flowers.jpg  |   blabla.ashx?SequenceNumber=1
          2           |   light.jpg    |   blabla.ashx?SequenceNumber=2
          3           |   garden.jpg   |   blabla.ashx?SequenceNumber=3
          4           |   candy.jpg    |   blabla.ashx?SequenceNumber=4
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML dataset you are using as input? Thank yoU!

Comment: @Wafae...is that really the input source? Is it not in XML format? Please post this and not a table view of data. We need to see specific elements.

Comment: @Parfait Yeah, that is exactly the input source. The dataset is a table result from a stored procedure. The only thing i changed in here is the 'src' for the images in the table result, everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: @TimC I just edited with an example for the dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Forgive me @Wafae, this input source is very relevant to include in your post for prospective answerers. What format is table in -csv, txt? What RDMS - SQL Server, Oracle? Curious how are your running this XSLT? What XSLT engine? From Mgmt Studio or an SSIS script? You could consider a [TSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) solution.

Comment: Do you want all the images displayed in a row, or perhaps you want to limit the number shown, to (for example) 5 per row?

Comment: @TimC yes, i want the images displayed in a row. I am limiting the images to 4 four images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I can give a precise answer, but as a starter, you probably want to have a template that matches the main dataset (the parent of all the `Photos` element), where you can construct the table row.

If you just wanted to show the first 4 only, you could start off by doing this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Photos:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Photos[position() &lt; 5]" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Photos">
        <td>
            <a href = '{src}'  style="font-size:10px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>
            </a>
            <br />
            <img Width="75" Height="75" src='{src}' />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have simplified the "Photos" templates because tables nested within tables is really not recommended.

On the other hand, if you have more than 4 photos and want to show 4 per row, you would select the first photo that would appear at the start of each row (i.e the photos in position 1, 5, 9, etc), and then build a row up from each of those.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Photos:</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Photos[position() mod 4 = 1]">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Photos[position() &lt; 4]" />
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Photos">
        <td>
            <a href = '{src}'  style="font-size:10px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>
            </a>
            <br />
            <img Width="75" Height="75" src='{src}' />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```